# Weglot country-selector not really inline and unwanted hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, translation

We have got a Woocommerce store and made it multilingual with the weglot-plugin. In desktop view, we integrated the country-selector next to the shopping cart. For mobile view, we took the HTML-Widget and put it in the header surrounded by some code:

```
<div class="only-mobile">
  <center>
    <small>
      <div id="weglot_here"></div>
    </small>
  </center>
</div>
```

.only-mobile has the following code to it, only showing when in mobile mode respectively not showing when in desktop-mode:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.only-mobile{
         display: none !important;
    }
```

**Question 1**
As you can see, the ul-element for the second language is a bit lower than the first one. I wasn't sure how to adress that, as it has so many classes so I tried several things like styling the margin, v-align and display:inline directly in the code. Didn´t do anything.

**Question 2**
Second thing is, we dont want the second element to have that underlined blue hover, so I tried this:

```
.a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

I tried that to `.country-selector` and `.only-mobile` as well and did the same things with and without `:hover` after the class. Nothing happens. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question #2

```
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

You don't add the `.` because you're styling an html tag. Not a class, if you were to give an `a tag` a class name then you would use `.classname` .